# Web Scraping with Boost, Returning Hex not HTML

Tags: c++, boost, web-scraping

I am building a web scraper that downloads the HTML from a web page, parses it, and displays the time in the various time zones across the US. I got the [example code from Rosetta Code](http://www.rosettacode.org/wiki/Web_scraping#C.2B.2B). However, they use Boost 1.46.1 for Windows, where as I am using Boost 1.60.0 for Mac OSX. Below is the code that I have modified from the Rosetta Code Example in an effort to get it working.

```
#include <cstdlib>
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>
#include <boost/regex.hpp>
#include <boost/asio.hpp>
#include <boost/system/config.hpp>
#include <boost/asio/ip/tcp.hpp>    

void GetTime()
{   
    boost::asio::ip::tcp::iostream s("tycho.usno.navy.mil","http");
    cout << s << "\n";          //check to see what downloaded from URL
    if(!s){                     //if S = Null then nothing downloaded & connection not made
        cout << "Error! Not Connected." << endl;
        s << "Get /cgi-bin/timer.pl HTTP/1.0\r\n"
            << "host:tycho.usno.navy.mil\r\n"
            << "Acceot:*/*\r\n"
            << "Connection:closer\r\n\r\n";//error information provided
    }
    int count = 0;
    for (string line; getline(s, line);){
        boost::smatch matches;
        if(boost::regex_search(line, matches, boost::regex("<BR>'(.+\\s+UTC)'<BR>"))){
            cout << matches[count];//parse the HTML, if there is a match save it in matches[count]
            cout << ">> Matches" << count << "\n";
            //++ count;
            break;
        }
    ++ count;   
    cout << "End of For Loop.\n";//to check if the for loop ran
    }
    cout << "Finale Count: " << count << " End of Void GetTime.\n";//to check if the void was completed
}
```

The output:

```
0x7fff5fbff430
Final Count: 0 End of Void GetTime.

RUN FINISHED; exit value 0; real time: 20s; user: 0ms; system: 0ms
```

Based on the Final Count being "0", I can conclude that the program never enters the for-loop. Are the conditions of the For-Loop and If-statement correct for this application? Or is the problem with the the line boost::asio::ip::tcp::iostream s("tycho.usno.navy.mil","http"); line that is calling up the webpage and placing the HTML in string S?

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you've made mistake in error condition in first if. When I changed

```
if(!s) //if S = Null then nothing downloaded & connection not made
{
cout << "Error! Not Connected." << endl;
s << "Get /cgi-bin/timer.pl HTTP/1.0\r\n"
  << "host:tycho.usno.navy.mil\r\n"
  << "Acceot:*/*\r\n"
  << "Connection:closer\r\n\r\n";//error information provided
}
```

to

```
if(!s)
{
    cout << "Error! Not Connected." << endl;
    return;
}

s << "Get /cgi-bin/timer.pl HTTP/1.0\r\n"
  << "host:tycho.usno.navy.mil\r\n"
  << "Accept:*/*\r\n"
  << "Connection:closer\r\n\r\n";//error information provided
```

I got following output:

```
0x7ffdc0a5d730
End of For Loop.
End of For Loop.
End of For Loop.
End of For Loop.
End of For Loop.
End of For Loop.
End of For Loop.
End of For Loop.
End of For Loop.
End of For Loop.
End of For Loop.
End of For Loop.
End of For Loop.
End of For Loop.
End of For Loop.
End of For Loop.
Finale Count: 16 End of Void GetTime.
```

Which I think is expected output. Note that you also have typo in **Accept** word in your request.

Comment: I made your recommended changes, thank you. Can you please explain to me what: `s << "Get /cgi-bin/timer.pl HTTP/1.0\r\n"
  << "host:tycho.usno.navy.mil\r\n"
  << "Accept:*/*\r\n"
  << "Connection:closer\r\n\r\n";` is for?

Comment: This is HTTP request you're sending to host host:tycho.usno.navy.mil. You can think of it as opening http://host:tycho.usno.navy.mil/cgi-bin/timer.pl in your browser.

Comment: Thank you, I wasn't sure if this was the case. The code now enters the For-Loop, but not the `if(boost::regex_search(line, matches, boost::regex("<BR>'(.+\\s+UTC)'<BR>"))){`. Is this because what is downloaded from the HTTP in iostream is a hex value, and regex is looking for chars?

Comment: try to print `line` and you will find out what you received from server.

Comment: @Nate speaking of **Accept**, think to [accept the answer](http://stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer) if it suits you. You can do so by clicking on the big green check under this question's score.